# updating all data in one row sql server vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

im using vb.net 2005 and sql server 2005
i want to update all data in one row in one click button in vb.net
for example

```
  
stock | last_stock  
1        2   
1        3
1        4
```

if i click update button in my vb.net project it becomes

```
  
stock | last_stock  
2        2   
3        3
4        4
```

all i know is update single data, please help
i try with

```
update barang set (stock) ='" &textbox1.text& "' where barang.id_barang = transaksi.id_barang
```

Comment: So, what you actually mean is that you want to update all the data in one COLUMN, not one ROW, right?  If you want to update multiple rows then you simply have to use a WHERE clause that will match all those rows.  If you want to match every row then you just don't use a WHERE clause at all.

Comment: Are you trying to set the value of `stock` to the value of `last_stock` for each row?

Comment: @JonSenchyna yes i want to do that

Comment: @jmcilhinney without where like this <pre>update barang set (stock) ='" &textbox1.text& "</pre> but it will change all data in stock become one same value from textbox1

Comment: It will only do that if you specify the same value for every row.  If you want a different value for each row then use an expression that will evaluate to a different value for each row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without `WHERE` clause `UPDATE` will affect all rows in your table

```sql
UPDATE barang SET stock = last_stock
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ddd2e/1)** demo